# Spring Framework, загрузка файлов и Jetty

Tags: java, spring

Столкнулся с проблемой загрузки файлов (точнее, приема multipart-запросов) в Spring, запущенном через Jetty. При multipart-запросе приложение отвечает пятисотой ошибкой без вывода, в stdout появляется такой трейс:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected MultipartHttpServletRequest: is a MultipartResolver configured?
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestPartMethodArgumentResolver.java:123)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
    ...
```

При этом bean multipartResolver объявлен в конфигурации:

```
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(maxUploadSize);
    resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    return resolver;
}
```

Само объявление контроллера максимально простое:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<Document> upload(@PathVariable long id, @RequestPart("content") MultipartFile content) {
...
```

Все найденные ссылки рекомендуют вопрошающим либо создать вышеупомянутый бин, что, насколько я понимаю, я уже сделал, либо заменить `@RequestParam` на `@RequestPart`, что тоже было сделано. При отправке curl'ом запроса я  вижу заголовок multipart/form-data, судя по Content-Length, файл действительно шлется. В чем может быть причина ошибки?

P.S. Проблема может быть совсем простой и глупой, я до сих пор не освоился в Java и Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась довольно тривиальной (ну а как еще): метод, вызываемый по цепочке из CommonsMultipartResolver, проводил проверку текущего метода на соответствие POST, а я пытался использовать PUT. [Этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12617195/2908793) ответ подсказал решение, достаточно создать бин из отнаследованного от CommonsMultipartResolver класса, в котором переопределен метод `boolean isMultipartContent(HttpServletRequest request)`.